# How to perform XOR operations on every X consecutive rows numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a Python numpy array like this Let's call it 
**my_numpy_array** And can go up to a million values!

```
>>> my_numpy_array
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       . . . . . . . . . . . . 
       . . . . . . . . . . . . 
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

and another numpy array like this call it **second_array** ,(which is not so huge)

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],      #row 1
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],      #row 2
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       .......................        #row 9
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])     #can be any number of ROWS!!!
```

I want to XOR these 9 (this is X..i.e can be any number) rows with every 9 rows in **my_numpy_array**. I tried working around with `np.logical_xor()`  but could'nt do what I wanted!

Also note if the number of rows in **my_numpy_arr** is not a multiple of 9 (i.e X) say the no of rows is 2701..

for the first 2700 no problem! but the last one will be XOR-ed with only the first one from the **second_array**

if it was 2702 then only the first two rows from the **second_array**..

Any help much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: `repeat`

```
x = np.ones((271, 10))
y = np.zeros((9, 10))
np.logical_xor(x, np.repeat(y, x.shape[0]//y.shape[0]+1, axis=0)[:x.shape[0],:])
```

Method 1 is to `repeat` `y` enough times and subset the part that fits `x`'s row part.

---

Method 2: `reshape`

```
def method2(x, y):
    ry, ly = y.shape
    rx, lx = x.shape
    arr1 = np.logical_xor(x[:rx//ry*ry].reshape((ry, ly, rx // ry)), 
                          y.reshape((ry, ly, 1)))
    arr2 = np.logical_xor(x[rx//ry*ry:], y[:rx%ry, :]) # remainder part
    return np.append(arr1.reshape((arr1.shape[0]*arr1.shape[2], arr1.shape[1])), 
                     arr2, axis=0)
```

For method 2, we split the original `x` into two parts: the part is a multiple of `y`'s row part and the remainder part. Take OP's problem for example, we split 2702 rows into 2700 rows and 2 rows because 2700 is a multiple of 9 and 2 is the remainder part. (The purpose of the messay part inside square brackets, like `[:rx//ry*ry]`, is to do the split.)

For the 2700-row part, we can reshape it as a 3 dimensional tensor with shape (9, X, 30). Then, we reshape `y` as (9, X, 1). In this case, while performing the operation `np.logical_xor`, `y` will be broadcasted as the same size of `(9, X, 30)`. See [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more information.

We also perform xor for the 2-row part and then use `np.append` to glue these two results.

**Timing**: **For Large x, method 2 is faster**

```
x = np.ones((2720000, 10))
y = np.zeros((9, 10))

%timeit method2(x, y)
52.5 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit np.logical_xor(x, np.repeat(y, x.shape[0]//y.shape[0]+1, axis=0)[:x.shape[0],:])
175 ms ± 5.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`repeat` creates a new array that is the same size of `x` while the second broadcasting/`reshape` method do not do so. Thus, `repeat` could cost more time when `x` is big.

Comment: That is wild! :)

Comment: @erip what do you mean wild...?

Comment: Interesting to look at.

Comment: @Tai `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types,` is coming

Comment: ah I cant even understand anything... pls can u explain a bit .for a beginner

Comment: @poda_badu added some details. Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

If the XOR filter is just one row, you could simply use numpy broadcasting:

```
arr = np.asarray([ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

filt = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

res = arr ^ filt
```

If not, it doesn't look so pretty:

```
arr = np.asarray([ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

filt = np.asarray([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])


filt_rows = filt.shape[0]
arr_rows = arr.shape[0]

res = arr ^ np.tile(filt, (1 + arr_rows // filt_rows ,1))[:arr_rows,:]
```

The filter rows are tiled to a larger array than your `my_numpy_array` and then cut back by indexing, so both arrays have the same shape. Not sure, how this works with larger sizes, since it makes a copy of the array and doesn't work in place.